# PHP Update script not reflecting changes in form

Tags: php

I am creating simple `PHP` update script. In that, whenever I update data form does not shows updated data. Means update query work and record is updated successfully but updated data does not reflects in text box in form. But whenever I `refresh/redirect` page again then it shows updated text in text box. Below is the code.

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("test");

    if(isset($_POST['update']))
    {
      $txt =  $_POST['txt'];
      $que= mysql_query("update test set test='$txt' where id='1'");
    }
    $que= mysql_query("select * from test where id=1");
    $data=mysql_fetch_array($que); 
    $test = $data[0];

?>
  <form method="post">
   <input type="text" name="txt" value="<?php echo $test; ?>">
   <button name="update">Update</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: do not use `mysql_query` instead use `PDO` or `mysqli`

Answer (score 0):

You forget to write `type="submit"` and **Major bugs are fixed**

Use this

```
<?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("test");

    $que= mysql_query("select * from test where id=1");
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($que);

    if(isset($_POST['update']))
    {
        $txt =  $_POST['txt'];
        $que= mysql_query("update test set test='$txt' where id='1'");

    }


?>
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="txt" value="<?php if(!empty($data)){ echo $data; } else { } ?>">
    <button name="update" type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

> **Warning**
>   This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the `MySQLi` or `PDO_MySQL` extension should be used.

and Read [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

change the type to submit and add the action.

```
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
  $txt =  $_POST['txt'];
  $que= mysql_query("update test set test='$txt' where id='1'");
}
$que= mysql_query("select * from test where id=1");
$data=mysql_fetch_array($que); 
$test = $data[0];
?>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="txt" value="<?php echo $test;?>">
<input type="submit" name="update" value="Update">
</form>
```